# JQuery Delete Row on dynamic tables

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, dynamic-tables

I'm creating a registration page where the user can register several other people. I've made it so that the table only shows if the user selects a certain option. I've also added the add button and that adds rows perfectly fine. The problem is when I add the function for the delete button everything breaks. Here's my html:

```
<div id="add_table" style="display:none;" >
    <button type="button" id="AddLine">Add Line</button>
    <table border="1px" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Ethnicity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><button type="button">delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>​
</div>
```

And here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("input[name= 'Reg_num_r']").change( function () {
        if($(this).val()==1) {
            $("#add_table").hide();
        } else {
            $("#add_table").show();
        }
    });

    /*$("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
       $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
    });​*/

    $("#AddLine").click(function () {
        var row = "<tr><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td>                   <input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><button type=button>delete</button></td></tr>";
        $("#table").append(row);
    });
});
```

Now when I uncomment the commented code above, everything stops working. The table just doesn't show up even if the user selects the right option. How should I fix it so it properly executes the delete row operation?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FJfwX/). What version of jQuery are you using? `on` was introduced in 1.7.

Comment: This is so weird... the commented code seems ok. Which version of jQuery are you using? Are you remembering to remove both the opening `/*` and the ending `*/` of the comment?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Yah I know, i tried the same thing which is why i posted here. I am so confused, how does it work in fiddle and not in practicality.

Comment: @aziz.punjani how do i check in the console. Is that with firefox and firebug?

Comment: In chrome/safari there's developer tools, in ie there's developer tools and in firefox there's firebug but i belive the newer version has developer tools built in. What browser are you using ?

Comment: Where is the input with name Reg_num_r defined? How is it being set? I see no problem when uncommenting that part of the code if I make the div visible before

Comment: @Richard: Yep, you'll definitely want to use Firebug with FireFox. Enable it and then look at the "console" tab to see any errors that occurred.

Comment: NEVERMIND, it's seriously just magic'ed. I really have no explanation for it but it just works now....Does anyone know how I can set a cap on the table? Can only enter certain amount of entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> from your code:

```
/*$("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});​*/
```

There's a 0-width space after the last semi-colon, click edit and use the arrow keys to see it. It's an illegal character in JavaScript and generates a Syntax Error.

That's a common problem when copying code from jsFiddle and other places.

I'd recommend having a copy of [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) at hand to review copypasta code, it displays those invisible characters as `?` by default:

[image]

You may also uncomment the code and test it in [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), it will tell you in what line there's an invalid character.